# Need recovery of original JASON file for 3000 ether

Tags: ether

Is it possible to have your original JASON file you were sent in the Pre-sale re-sent. I have the password, but the file was never saved on my hard drive and my emails were deleted.  The link was saved and not the file I had my hard drive forensically searched for the file, but no luck.  Google is saying that the email is permanently deleted from the summer of 2014 and they won't help me. We have looked at the history of Google and they have went back 11 years and retrieved emails for court cases where a man was found not guilty by retrieving his old emails from 11 years earlier. Can anyone help me here as the file is worth millions at present.

Comment: From this https://github.com/ethereum/pyethsaletool presale wallet were generated by each individual and never sent to the Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

To recover your lost account you need either:

- private key
- mnemonic phrase
- keystore file

---

I can assume you are asking how to restore your keystore file and to do so you need to have your **private key** and **password**. If you don't have a private key try to find your mnemonic phrase.